# ShortCut for showing all the constructor overloads in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense, constructor-overloading

What is the way to show all the overloads of a constructor in C++ in Visual Studio 2022?

Suppose I have a `Rectangle` class, and I have 3 overloads for them. When I hover my mouse in any of them, Intellisense shows a box with the current overload and says I have +4 overloads.

Is there a way I can see the other overloads in that box by pushing any shortcut key? In other words, is there any way I can see/skim through all the overloads in that box, rather than going into the code and trying to find out what the other overloads are?

I have tried to use <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Space</kbd> after putting my cursor inside `()`. That did not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the overloads of a method/function/constructor by **calling it** then a list of overloads will appear eg. [exmaple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIBJ7.png) and if you lose the focus (and the list disappeared) you can press `Ctrl+Shift+Space` on windows or `⌘+Shift+Space` on mac only to refocus. this works for () and {} but you must put your cursor inside ()/{} as you mentioned in the question.

Sadly you can't see all the overloads just by move the cursor to the header as in your example but you could instead do something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIBJ7.png) (call the constructor and see the list of overloads).

Comment: I think it's an effective workaround to show all the constructor overloads by calling it in your code. You can skim through all the overloads easily in this way. If it gives some help, you could  accept the answer, this will help other users who has the same issue.